# Order by formatted sum of Double

Tags: mysql

Given a DOUBLE  (cannot change), how can I order by the sum of the formatted column?

```
 +------+-----+
 |  id  | val |
 +------+-----+
    2   | 1289.42
    2   | 43.21
    3   | 90.02
```

With my attempts it seems the order by is only ordering by the first couple of digits:

```
select format(sum(val), 2) 
group by id
order by val DESC
```

The results are the same if I attempt to use an alias

```
select format(sum(val), 2) as res
group by id
order by res DESC
```

Current output:

```
90.02 <--- looks to only order by first few numbers 
1,332.63
```

Desired output:

```
1,332.63 <----higher values first 
90.02
```

Comment: `order by sum(val) desc`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: Yes, it was that simple ;_; thanks